# Event on one element to trigger event on another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll use a specific example but this could apply to *any* event on one element triggering *any* event on another.  Suppose that we want to **focus** an `<input>` when we **click** a `<span>`.  We can do this using a directive like:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span ng-focus-other>focus</span><input>
<div>

app.directive("ngFocusOther", function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        element.bind("click", function () {
            this.nextSibling.focus();
        });
    };
});
```

However this does not seem very *Angular*.  This would also not work were there any changes to the DOM (e.g. if `<input>` were moved *before* `<span>`).  It would also be nice if the same code could work on multiple groups of `<span>`-`<input>` combinations perhaps each with a different DOM layout.

What is the Angular way of using one event to trigger another event on another element?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply have clicking the span set a boolean called "inputFocused" to true and then let the input pay attention to that scope variable. I.e.

```
<span ng-click="inputFocused = true">FOCUS</span>
<input ng-focus="inputFocused" value="GIVE ME FOCUS">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/500/ -- this doesn't seem to work; am I missing something?

Comment: @ExplosionPills seems like `ngFocus` is added in latest versions: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngFocus

Comment: @Cherniv in my jsfiddle I'm including a supposedly working ng-focus directive

Comment: @Fourth How can I create an isolate scope for this as well since I'm using already-defined directives?  There could be multiple groups of span-input

Comment: I am unsure of the ng-focus directive that you are using. The one I was referring to comes from angular 1.2.0 rc-2. If you are trying to use an isolate scope for that directive, just two-way bind it and use watches.